# How to take a string with variable length decimal places, and convert it to a whole number uint?

Tags: solidity, oracles, string

I'm experimenting with writing an ethereum-usd price ticker taking data from the coinmarketcap API using Oraclize's API.

I noticed that Oraclize has a function called `parseInt` that can be used to remove the numbers after the decimal from a string (such as 10.99) an turn it into the uint 10.

As far as I can tell this *ONLY* works with strings that have a FIXED length after the decimals. As per CMCs API, the length after the decimal is variable in length. I've noticed it being values such as 1000.99 or 1000.991

I'm unable to figure out how to parse this string of a variable decimal length and turn it into a whole number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my reading of [the code](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol#L630) and testing in Remix, I think you're mistaken. `parseInt("1000.99")` and `parseInt("1000.991")` should both return `1000`.

There's an optional parameter that basically says what power of 10 to multiply by. `parseInt("100.99", 2)` and `parseInt("1000.991")` should both return `100099`.

Comment: Ah yes I was indeed mistaken. Thanks for the answer that makes things a lot more clear now.